# Compile MOF using C#

Tags: c#

How can i compile MOF to C# class (via C# code)? is mofcomp.exe can do that (if so, how?)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about... What is MOF? Microsoft Operations Framework?

Comment: The CIM Specification defines the syntax and rules of the model, including the CIM syntax language called MOF (Managed Object Format).

Answer (score 1):

mofcomp doesn't generate code from MOFs. It parses a file containing MOF statements and adds the classes and class instances defined in the file to the WMI repository, and has some more several options. See here: [mofcomp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392389(VS.85).aspx)

AFAIK, there is no ready-to-use tool which does so. You need to write it by yourself.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The [mgmtclassgen.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mgmtclassgen-exe) program can create a strongly typed version of a WMI class. This utility is included with the .NET SDK. If you have Visual Studio installed, you can access it from the Developer Command Prompt. The code generator can also be programatically accessed through the [ManagementClass.GetStronglyTypedClassCode method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementclass.getstronglytypedclasscode).

To create a strongly typed C# class of the Win32_LogicalDisk WMI class, you could use the following command:

```
Mgmtclassgen.exe Win32_LogicalDisk
```

This will create a LogicalDisk.CS file containing a `LogicalDisk` class.

If the contents of the MOF file is not already in your computer's WMI repository, you have to first use [mofcomp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/mofcomp) to install the classes and instances:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\mofcomp.exe your_file.mof
```